# "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" using DB Singleton

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a small API to abstract a personal database for my personal site. I decided the best course of action was to use a singleton for the Database Connection and then create controllers for each table I want to grab values from. I apologize for *yet another* `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object` question but I haven't seen one where the first call works and then fails on subsequent calls. To demonstrate that, I'm calling the same method twice. It works once, gives me that dreaded error after.

I think it might have to do with the singleton object -- maybe the connection is closing after the call? Or maybe I'm not closing the current query correctly if I'm to reuse the object? Onto the code:

**DatabaseConnection.php**

```
include_once('./helpers/Config.php');

class DatabaseConnection{
private static $instance;

private function __construct(){}

private function __clone() { }

public static function getInstance()
{
    if(!isset(self::$instance))  
    {
        self::$instance = new MySQLi(Config::$database_hostname, Config::$database_user, Config::$database_password, Config::$database_name);
        if(self::$instance->connect_error)
            throw new Exception('MySQL connection failed: '.self::$instance->connect_error);

    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

}

**SkillController.php**

```
include_once('./singletons/DatabaseConnection.php');
include_once('./helpers/JsonConverter.php');
include_once('./models/Skill.php');
class SkillController extends JsonConverter
{
    public function getAllItems()
    {
        $i = 0;
        $results = array();
        $sqlResult = DatabaseConnection::getInstance()->query("CALL S_SKILLS");

        while($row = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $results[$i] = new Skill($row['Title'], $row['Ranking']);
            $i++;
        }

        return $this->toJson($results);
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

include_once("controllers/SkillController.php");

print "Controller: ".$_GET['controller']."<br/>";
print "ID: ".$_GET['id']."<br/>";

$test = new SkillController();
echo($test->getAllItems()."<br />");
echo($test->getAllItems()."<br />");

?>
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm purposely making this harder than it has to be to provide as a source code sample in the future as part of my website, which I want to showcase my skills as a developer. Unfortunately, I've spent the majority of my coding career on the Microsoft side of the fence so all these PHP nuisances are hitting me hard.

**Edit**
Here is the output to `index.php` (truncated):

```
Controller: 
ID: 
object(mysqli_result)#3 (0) { } [{"Title":"HTML5","Ranking":"9999"},{"Title":"CSS","Ranking":"200"},{"Title":"JavaScript","Ranking":"200"},{"Title":"C#","Ranking":"190"},...,{"Title":"IBM 360 Assembly","Ranking":"25"},{"Title":"Python","Ranking":"25"}]
bool(false)
```

Comment: `var_dump($sqlResult);`

Comment: You run straight into `$sqlResult->fetch_Assoc()` without testing `$sqlResult`

Comment: Using `var_dump` it looks like the second call is returned as false. http://api.horodyski.me <-- check it out there. Works first time, not the second. Need to rank PHP a bit lower :-P

Answer (score 0):

The call to execute a query returns `false` if it fails or has no data to return. That is why your `while()` is failing.

Comment: See updated post. I included what I get back on the index page. It looks like somewhere the connection is failing when I make a subsequent call.

Comment: I'd be looking at the error condition on the database handler, then. It should tell you why you lost the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: I had to step into the error and found `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`. I found out that stored procedures bring back two results -- I think. In any case, here is the solution. Thanks to @staticsan to leading me to it.

```
class SkillController extends JsonConverter
{
    public function getAllItems()
    {
        $i = 0;
        $results = array();
        $sqlResult = DatabaseConnection::getInstance()->query("CALL S_SKILLS");

        if($sqlResult)
        {
            while($row = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $results[$i] = new Skill($row['Title'], $row['Ranking']);
                $i++;
            }
            $sqlResult->close();
            DatabaseConnection::getInstance()->next_result();
        }

        return $this->toJson($results);
    }
}
```